# Disable a conditionally formatted combobox based on a checkbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have a combobox in access that is conditionally formatted to change colors based off what the user picked.  The reason it's formatted that way is because it is running continuous forms.  The combobox is called VettingCombo if you need that.  Now I have a checkbox, named Lock, that when you check it, it will disable every item in the form.  This works all the time EXCEPT when the conditional formatting is in place.  So say the combobox is now blue because of the choice they made, if I hit the lock button it will not disable that combobox.  I tried making another condition where Expression is [Lock] = True but that didn't work.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it to remain 'blue' but locked? Or can you reset the color before locking?

Comment: I'd like it to remain blue after being disabled, but not required

Comment: Let's see how you're conditionally formatting `VettingCombo`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, had to move the expression to the top of the conditional format list